# Move directory to

Tags: 14.04, mv

I'm trying to move directory with all content to one level up.

```
machine:/opt/jre8# rm  jre1.8.0_60 ..
```

have error:

```
rm: cannot remove `jre1.8.0_60': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove `.' or `..'
```

I expect to place `jre1.8.0_60` that is in `/opt/jre8/` to `/opt/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use the `rm` command which is the remove command, where you really need the `mv` command to move the directory. Other than using the wrong command your syntax looks good.

The correct command would be:

```
mv jre1.8.0_60 ..
```

or

```
mv jre1.8.0_60 /opt/
```

This does depend on having the correct privileges to move the directory, so the command may need to insert `sudo` before the command.